# How do easily I import eclipse android project into Intellij IDEA 10

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have an Android project in eclipse and would like to move to Intellij IDEA.
But I didn't find easy way to import existing **android** project.
General project import doesn't recognize that my project for Android.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you add the android SDK....Right click on the project -> Open Module Settings -> Facets

More info can be found [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/10/intellij-idea-10-free-ide-for-android-development/) in  the comments, specifically there's [an article from jetbrain's wiki](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_Android_using_existing_sources)